# How to Get version from Comments of *.msi file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need get version of [GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi](http://dl.google.com/edgedl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi) installer from CMD, but the version only is shown in Comments. I tried with WMIC without success.
Regards.

```
wmic datafile where "name='E:\\BACKUP\\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi'" get /format:list
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the `WMIC` command you tried, by adding it to your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49321092/edit) facility, _(highlighting it and clicking on the `{}` button to format it as code)_.

Comment: Why are you using `E:\\BACKUP\\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi` when the image clearly shows the full path as `F:\TEMP\Chrome\{tmp}\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi`?

Comment: Because I get image from other PC with english language...

Comment: The version of that particular executable is not available from the WMIC data returned so you'll need to find another way of getting it. _Questions asking for software/tool recommendations are off-topic here, so this is not the appropriate place for asking for that_.

Comment: It is unlikely however that other versions will have the same `FileSize` property so that may be an comparison option for you moving forward. `WMIC DataFile Where "Name='E:\\BACKUP\\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi'" Get FileSize /Value`.

Comment: I think your real question starts with from where the File > Properties > Details page gets its information. It does not appear to be from the same place as `wmic` or `VersionInfo`.

Comment: I don't need especifically WMIC, only a way to get version of installer from cmd or other alternative method...

Comment: As I stated previously requests for software and tools are off topic here. You need to find an alternative programming method yourself through research. If you find one and your question hasn't been deleted you can [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49321092/edit), with the new code and information required to make it on-topic. Perhaps asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) would be a better move.

Comment: Pretty sure Vbscript has an object to pull all that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a surprisingly easy solution (also surprisingly weird - I can imagine it doesn't work for all files):

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('find "Copyright" "D:\tmp\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi"') do set "version=%%a"
echo Version: %version%
```

add a `"delims="`, if you need the whole line `65.0.3325.162 Copyright 2011 Google Inc.`

EDIT: combining the speed of `findstr` with the (in this case better) line-break parsing of `find`:

```
for /f %%a in ('findstr "Copyright" "GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi" ^|find "Copyright"') do set "version=%%a"
```

Comment: `findstr` is much faster, but returns a lot of unneeded crap.

Comment: Can you give me a example with findstr...?

Comment: see the edit in my answer. For `findstr` alone, you get something like `Installer   ▲   )   65.0.3325.162 Copyright 2011 Google Inc.    ▲   ♂   Intel;1033  ▲   '   {F04E9D75-81B1-4201-AD51-3E824A5878BA}  @    f↔²b║╙☺@    f↔²b║╙☺♥   û   ♥   ☻   ▲   +   Windows Installer XML Toolset (3.8.1128.0)  ♥   ☻           ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠ ♠`

Comment: Thanks again... ;-)